# Using .Net standard assemblies in Silverlight 5

Tags: .net, silverlight, .net-core, portable-class-library, .net-standard

Can or will .Net Core assemblies build using the .Net standard be compatible with Silverlight 5?

Ideally binary compatible but a re-compile is fine also. And if they are, is there any documentation on how to create such assemblies?

I could not find anything about Silverlight in the documentation at e.g. [.Net Standard Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/articles/standard/library)

Comment: Have you tried referencing such a library from a Silverlight project?

Comment: Just tried it again and neither project references in solution as well as assembly references work. Project references are denied from VS and assembly references fail to build.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Only Silverlight what is supported (on .Net Standard 1.0) is Windows Phone Silverlight 8.0. More information https://github.com/dotnet/standard/blob/master/docs/versions.md

Comment: Any idea about re-compiling .Net Standard code for Silverlight, or how far the libraries are apart?

Comment: @sanosdole, For Silverlight compatibility you need Portable Libraries, which predate .Net Standard.  They are very limited.  Silverlight's end of life is in 2021, and already the only browser that still supports it is InternetExplorer.  There will be now new editions.  It's worth considering a migration plan away from the technology.  https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webapps/2014/01/16/silverlight-support-roadmap/

Comment: And for compatibility: https://www.microsoft.com/getsilverlight/locale/en-us/html/installation-win-SL5.html

Answer (score 1):

The only way to reference the same DLL from both Silverlight and .Net is to use a [Portable Class Library (PCL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/cross-platform/cross-platform-development-with-the-portable-class-library).  Since PCL's have to be cross-platform, and the technology predates .Net Standard you will be pretty limited in what you can do in a PCL (more limited than what you can do in Silverlight).

Since Silverlight is already on the path to [being sunsetted](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webapps/2014/01/16/silverlight-support-roadmap/), there will be no new features for the technology.  Only bug fixes and security patches until October 2021.  Silverlight's compatibility has been shrinking since the announcement, and [all modern browsers have dropped support](https://www.microsoft.com/getsilverlight/locale/en-us/html/installation-win-SL5.html) (or never had it).

The list of browsers that do not support Silverlight include:

- Firefox since version 52.0
- Chrome since they [disabled NPAPI support](https://www.chromium.org/developers/npapi-deprecation)
- Safari since ersion 9.x
- Microsoft Edge (never added support)

All have also disabled flash support as well.  The only browser that still supports Silverlight is Internet Explorer.

Since there are 3 years left (as of 2018) till Silverlight will be completely dead, I would recommend migrating away from it and using standards based HTML5/CSS3/JavaScript6 solutions.

Comment: Thanks for the additional effort. We're already looking for alternatives, even before this question. This question was part of an intermediate step for the move away from Silverlight.

Comment: @sanosdole, I'm running into the same things with a project I'm on now, so all the info is fresh.  I have successfully put the bulk of the domain logic in a PCL so that I could test it with MSTest and use it in Silverlight.  Worked pretty well for that purpose, but I had to create some interfaces so I could inject URL encode/decode support and anything to do with a FileInfo.

Answer (score 0):

Thread is kinda old, but if you're still looking for a Silverlight app migration, you might want to take a look at this : http://www.cshtml5.com

It allows you to keep the existing C# and XAML code, and compile the files to HTML5 and JavaScript.

They also have a guide dedicated to SL migration :http://www.cshtml5.com/links/migrating-from-silverlight.aspx